# AVPlayer not stop playing when going back to the previous view

Tags: swift, swift3, avplayer

I have two View Controllers a TableViewController where I have a list of musics and a UIViewController where it plays the music. The music automatically plays when the view is loaded and pauses when the pause button is pressed.

However whenever I go back to the previous TableViewController to select another music, the music continues to play. And if i select another music, both of them are playing together.

My Codes:

```
var audioplayer = AVPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    play()
}

func play(){

    var songUrl = songList[selectedItem].url

    audioplayer = AVPlayer(url: songUrl!)

    audioplayer.play()

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use `.pause()` ? example:

```
var audioplayer: AVPlayer? = AVPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    play()
}

func play(){

    var songUrl = songList[selectedItem].url

    audioplayer = AVPlayer(url: songUrl!)

    audioplayer.play()

}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    audioplayer.pause()
    audioplayer = nil
}
```

Comment: If I write code in viewDidDisappear like this then we I close the view player will be stop and I do not want it.

Comment: Then it looks like you will have to re-structure your project. I am not sure what you want to happen, as this last comment seems to contradict your original question. You need to give more details.

Answer (score 0):

I already fixed my problem. I remove all player items in view controller and create new class for player. Now ıt ıs workıng smoothly.